# How to return key/value pair with getJSON of localhost URL in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsfiddle

I have followed [this tutorial](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/build-an-api-under-30-lines-of-code-with-python-and-flask/) to build an API using Python, Flask, SQLite, and SQLAlchemy. I can successfully hit the localhost address in my browser.  However, is it possible to test this connection and yield the desired results elsewhere, such as JSFiddle?

I would like to use this URL `http://localhost:5000/dept/police` to retrieve all of the salary key and value pairs

Sample JSON

```
{
    "data": [{
        "department": "POLICE",
        "name": "AARON,  JEFFERY M",
        "position": "POLICE OFFICER",
        "salary": "$80778.00"
    }, {
        "department": "POLICE",
        "name": "AARON,  KARINA",
        "position": "POLICE OFFICER",
        "salary": "$80778.00"
    }, {
        "department": "POLICE",
        "name": "ABBATE,  TERRY M",
        "position": "POLICE OFFICER",
        "salary": "$86520.00"
    }, {
        "department": "POLICE",
        "name": "ABBOTT,  LYNISE M",
        "position": "CLERK III",
        "salary": "$43920.00"
    }, {
        "department": "POLICE",
        "name": "ABDALLAH,  ZAID",
        "position": "POLICE OFFICER",
        "salary": "$69684.00"
    }, {
        "department": "POLICE",
        "name": "ABDELHADI,  ABDALMAHD",
        "position": "POLICE OFFICER",
        "salary": "$80778.00"
    }]
}
```

Comment: you can not hit your localhost API from Fiddler, you need to host your APIs on some publicly available server and that path fiddler can access. P.S. you will have to provide access to all in CORS call as well

Comment: Both @Deep and Roysh are wrong. It can be done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. JSFiddle is running on client side, so it is able to access you `locahost`.

But you have to pay attention to a few details to make it work.

1. CORS must be enabled on your local server. See how to do it [here](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).
2. You can't access JSFiddle trough `https`, if you do that your browser probably will block your request due to security measures. Read more [here](http://mzl.la/1klqkmQ).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fytov16/1/) I made. It is able to access my `localhost`with no problems.